# PostgreSQL default_statistics_target not improving row estimation

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize our queries on Postgres which takes minutes sometimes using huge tables. Started looking at query plan and noticed close 1000x difference between estimated number of rows and actual rows on running with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

This lead me to the parameter `default_statistics_target` which controls the number rows sampled by `ANALYZE` command to collect stats used by query planner. As few blogs suggested, I experimented by increased value setting it to `1000` and event to max allowed value of `10000`.

Ran `ANALYZE` every time to ensure it stats are updated. But surprisingly, this did not improve the rows estimation at all. In fact it reduced the estimated value a bit further which seems strange to understand.

Also tested by reducing the value to `10`. Which seems to have improved the count a bit. So I am confused if the param actually does what I thought it does. Or if there is some other way to improve row estimation. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Postgres version: 9.6**

**Query plan**: At the last index scan step, it has estimated 462 but actual is 1.9M.
https://explain.depesz.com/s/GZY

After changing `default_statistics_target = 1000`, rows at Index scan step were

```
->  (cost=0.57..120.42 rows=114 width=32) (actual time=248.999..157947.395 rows=1930518 loops=1)
```

And on setting it to `default_statistics_target = 10`, counts were:

```
->  (cost=0.57..2610.79 rows=2527 width=32) (actual time=390.437..62668.837 rows=1930518 loops=1)
```

P.S. Table under consideration has more than 100M rows.

Comment: Could it be that the value calculated by the InitPlan is a most common value for `event_name_id`? What is the query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added query. Yes. Value returned by subquery would be most common value for event_name_id in events table. That should get much better estimation right?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a correlation problem.  The planner assumes that the conditions on project_id, event_name_id, and "timestamp" are independent and so multiplies their estimated selectivity.  If they are not independent, then no amount of traditional statistics is going to help that.  Maybe you need [extended statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html)

Also, at the time it makes the plan it doesn't even know what value event_name_id will be compared to, as $0 is not determined until run time, so it can't use the value-specific statistics for that.  You could execute the subquery manually, then hard code the resulting value into that spot in the query, so the planner knows what the value is while it is planning.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to extended statistics. Will check on that if it helps. And makes sense that $0 value will not be know until runtime so it does not know that it is going to be the most common value. So I guess by default it assumes stats for general non frequent values (which are plenty).

Comment: Sadly extended statistics were added from Postgres 10. We are using 9.6.
Can something else be done without upgrading the version?

Comment: When planning for $0, I think it just assumes the rows returned will be estimated number of rows divided by estimated distinct values, so yes the existence of many rare values will drag the estimate down.  Running the subquery yourself then hardcoding the actual value should at least help the estimate, though you might also have a correlation which can't be helped in 9.6.  But it is not obvious to me that better row estimates will actually lead to a better plan anyway.  Maybe you return so many rows that the seq scan would be better, but that is far from clear.

Comment: In 9.6, max_parallel_workers_per_gather defaults to zero.  You might try changing that if you have multiple CPUs.  But parallel query was primitive back then, so it might not be very helpful.  Time spent upgrading is usually better spent than time spent working around issues caused by not upgrading.

Comment: Right. 9.6 might also soon go into unsupported versions list. Will definitely propose upgrading. Thanks for taking time to look into this.